# Class constructor issue C#

Tags: c#, class, syntax

I Have a class with this constructor , apperantly it doesn't seem to work. And before it was but I just forgot the syntax , could you remind me how to do it , please?

```
public class Excerscise
    {
        Excerscise(int t, double w, DateTime d) : tries(t), weight(w), date(d) {}
        int tries;
        double weight;
        DateTime date;
    }
```

Comment: If you just forgot, why don't you consult the documentation?

Comment: Clever way of saying "Please write this code for me"

Comment: Some people are not ashamed of anything it seems. Quote obviously for anyone bothering to read the documentation that is simply and totally not even C# code. Copy/paste/stare in agony at a compiler error one does not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
public class Excerscise {
  int tries;
  double weight;
  DateTime date;

  // it seems, that the constructor should be public
  public Excerscise(int t, double w, DateTime d) { 
    tries = t;
    weight = w;
    date = d;
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, forgot about putting constructor to public! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't support field initializer syntax like that (perhaps you come from a C++ background?). Do like so:

```
public class Exercise
{
    int tries;
    double weight;
    DateTime date;

    Exercise(int t, double w, DateTime d)
    {
        tries = t;
        weight = w;
        date = d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
class Program
    {
        class C2
        {
            int A;
            int B;
            public C2(int a, int b)
            {
                A = a;
                B = b;
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            C2 c = new C2(1, 2);
        }
    }
```